# SQL Server : checking 2 tables at once

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, join

OK , so what I'm trying to do basically is to check 2 tables in one query, one to see if the account has a flag enabled and the next to check to see if any account with an enabled flag has zero positive ratings (negative ratings are to be ignored)

So I basically have 2 tables

Table : `Accounts`

```
AccountId       Flag
--------     ---------
0001             1
0002             1
0003             0
0004             0
0005             0
0006             1
0007             1
0008             1
0009             1
```

Table :  `Ratings`

```
Accountid   Rating 
-------     --------
001         -1
001          3
001         -5
002          2
002          3
002          7
005          3
005          5
008          4
009         -4
009         -5
```

I can check the first table and get the ID's with the flag easily enough

```
select AccountId 
from Accounts 
where Flag = 1;

|  Account ID |  
---------------
|    001      |
|    002      |
|    006      |
|    007      |
|    008      |
|    009      |
```

but then I run into trouble checking ONLY the result of that query to find out which one doesn't have any positive ratings

If I was able to use php id be able to create an array and question each result one by one and come up with a result of 006,007 and 009

```
SELECT count(Rating) 
FROM Ratings 
WHERE Rating < 0 and AccountId = 001
1

SELECT count(Rating) 
FROM Ratings 
WHERE Rating < 0 and AccountId = 002
2

SELECT count(Rating) 
FROM Ratings 
WHERE Rating < 0 and AccountId = 006
0

SELECT count(Rating) 
FROM Ratings 
WHERE Rating < 0 and AccountId = 008
1
```

But I don't have that ability on this particular server so I need to be able to do it in one go using SQL Server (which I'm only starting to learn) ... any ideas on how I might manage it ?

Comment: With SQL don't think of arrays think of sets. Let SQL do the heavy lifting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think this works:

```
SELECT  A.accountid
FROM    accounts A
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  accountID ,
                            MAX(rating) AS rating
                    FROM    ratings
                    GROUP BY accountID
                  ) M ON A.accountID = M.accountID
WHERE   A.flag = 1
AND (M.rating IS NULL OR M.rating < 0)
```

It returns 006,007,009

006 and 007 are returned as there are no ratings at all for these in the ratings table and they are marked as active accounts.  009 is returned also as the maximum rating this received in the rating table is less than 0, so none of the ratings that this account received were positive.

Comment: This is perfect , and you even fixed the bit i overlooked with 007 as well - thanks a million , this was driving me mad - i have a lot to learn !!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.AccountId, count(Rating)
FROM Ratings r
JOIN Accounts a
    ON (a.AccountId = r.AccountId)
WHERE a.Flag = 1 AND r.Rating < 0
GROUP BY r.AccountId
```